# Gradle: How do I publish a zip from a non-java project and consume it in a java project?

Tags: build, gradle

I have a multi-project setup. I created a non-java project whose artifact is a zip file that I will unzip in another project. So the idea is as below

```
my-non-java-project
  build.gradle
  ------------
    apply plugin: 'base'

    task doZip(type:Zip) { ... }

    task build(dependsOn: doZip) << {
    }

    artifacts {
      archives doZip
    }


some-java-project
  build.gradle
  ------------
    apply plugin: 'war'
    configurations {
      includeContent // This is a custom configuration
    }
    dependency {
      includeContent project(':my-non-java-project')
    }

    task expandContent(type:Copy) {
      // Here is where I would like get hold of the all the files
      // belonging to the 'includeContent' configuration
      // But this is always turning out to be empty. Not sure how do I publish
      // non-java content to the local repository (as understood by groovy)
    }
```

So, my question is, how do I publish the artifacts of a non-java project to the internal repository of groovy such that I can pick it up at another java-based project?

Comment: Are you just trying to get access to the `outputs` of the `:my-non-java-project:doZip` task, or do you need to publish the zip to a repository (either on local file system or remote)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're after, but here's a quick-and-dirty way to get access to the [FileCollection](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html) of the `:my-non-java-project:doZip` task outputs:

```
project(":my-non-java-project").tasks.getByName("doZip").outputs.files
```

Note that the `archives` configuration [is added by the Java plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#tab:configurations), not the Base plugin. But you can still define a custom configuration in `my-non-java-project` and add the artifact to it with the code in your OP:

```
//in my-non-java-project/build.gradle
configurations {
    archives
}
artifacts {
    archives doZip
}
```

Then you can access the task outputs via the configuration, like so (again, quick-and-dirty):

```
//in some-java-project/build.gradle
project(":my-non-java-project").configurations.archives.artifacts.files
```

Note that you can expand the content of your zip file using [`zipTree`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:archive_contents).

If you need to actually publish the zip produced by `my-non-java-project`, you can [read about that here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#artifact_management).

Comment: Thank you for the solution. That solves the problem at hand. I have a decent amount of experience with ant+ivy and also understand how some of the internals operate. In the case of Gradle, I was trying to figure how does one publish an artifact (any file type) to the local Gradle repo (which is used by the Java/War plugin when the dependency is a project). Note, I am asking about the internal repo of Gradle and not about ivy / maven.